# Deprecated ActionScript Code, new code for linking flash to pdf?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, button, actionscript-2, hyperlink

I'm using Flash Pro. CS5 with ActionScript 3, and I've never worked with flash before, and I've searched for a while for the way to do this and I continuously get syntax errors with this code. I saw someone asked a similar question, and a person said the code was deprecated, so I can only assume since mine looks very similar that its also deprecated. From flash I'm trying to make a button that will open a PDF file. The code I have right now is;

```
on(release){
    getURL("Index Dividers.pdf");
}
```

and my syntax error keeps saying 'expecting semicolon before left brace' Stupid as it may sound, I added a semicolon before the left brace, and then one error turned into 3 errors, so that didnt solve anything. So does anyone know the proper code to open a PDF file? It will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getURL` has been replaced with `navigateToURL`, which works by accepting a `URLRequest` object.  In your case, it looks like this:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest('Index Dividers.pdf'));
```

As for the click handler, you can't you the `on(ACTION)` notation anymore, everything is event based now.  You need to set up a listener on your target, and assign a handler function to be called when the event fires:

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickHandler);

function clickHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest('Index Dividers.pdf'));
}
```

---

**A bit more about events:**

Firstly, an event.  An event can be thought of as a message that an object broadcasts when an action has occurred. The one we're using here is `MouseEvent.CLICK`.  This actually resolves to the string 'onClick', that is stored in the MouseEvent class, but don't worry about those details for now.  An object will broadcast this event when the user clicks it with their mouse.  Other mouse events include `MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER` and `MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT`.  There are other events for all kinds of things, and you can even create your own.

Now listeners.  In order to know when an event has been *dispatched* by an object, you add a listener to that object.  Using the example from above, we'll break it down:

`this.addEventListener` - we're saying that we want to listen for an event coming from the targeted object.  You have changed this in your code to target a button instance, which is perfect.

`(MouseEvent.CLICK,` - this is the event you want to listen for.

`clickHandler);` - this is the function that will be called as a result of the event being detected.

So now all you need is the function that we've named as the handler (the second parameter to `addEventListener`.  This function must accept one argument, an event object.  This is a reference to the actual instance of the event that was dispatched, and so for a mouse event it will be typecast as `MouseEvent`.  In the above example we didn't have any use for this object, but you must still have it in the function declaration or Flash will not compile.

Comment: Well I'm not getting an error msg with this code and I changed the 'this' to the instance name of the button (cause thats how it is in all the other codes)....I just have to figure out what a 'listener' is and how to assign 'handler functions'...both of which I'm not sure what they are heh. But thank you for your help!

Comment: I've added a brief and basic summary of events.  If you have any more specific questions please post a new question, and if you feel this has answered your question please accept the answer.

Answer (score -1):

if you change your actionscript version to `Actionscript 2` everything should be fine.

To do this, go to `file > Publish Settings > Flash > switch script version for 3 to 2`

Comment: I have 4 other buttons on there, and their all coded with ActionScript 3...wont I have to change all of them if I do that?

Comment: You would, and since you're new to Flash you're much better off learning AS3.